# How to make email field unique in model User from contrib.auth in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to patch the standard User model of `contrib.auth` by ensuring the email field entry is unique:

```
User._meta.fields[4].unique = True
```

Where is best place in code to do that?

I want to avoid using the number *fields[4]*. It's better to user *fields['email']*, but *fields* is not dictionary, only list.

Another idea may be to open a new ticket and upload a patch with new parameter inside `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True
```

Any suggestions on the most correct way to achieve email address uniqueness in the Django User model?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's amazing, but I found a best solution for me!

**django-registration** have form with checking uniqueness of email field: RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

example of usage [here](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration)

Comment: not to be an asshole, but I think you mean "uniqueness", not "unicity".

Comment: Link is dead. http://www.copyandwaste.com/posts/view/django-registration-require-a-unique-email-address-for-registration/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131533/django-registration-force-unique-e-mail for more info

Comment: But this will work for registration not for email update

Comment: that's @tgdn reasonable! but anyway the question and answer to much outdated, since we have custom user model  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 52):

> **Caution:**
>   The code below was written for an older version of Django (before [Custom
>   User Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) were introduced). It contains a race condition, and
>   should only be used with a Transaction Isolation Level of `SERIALIZABLE`
>   and request-scoped transactions.

Your code won't work, as the attributes of field instances are read-only. I fear it might be a wee bit more complicated than you're thinking.

If you'll only ever create User instances with a form, you can define a custom ModelForm that enforces this behavior:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email addresses must be unique.')
        return email
```

Then just use this form wherever you need to create a new user.

BTW, you can use `Model._meta.get_field('field_name')` to get fields by name, rather than by position. So for example:

```
# The following lines are equivalent
User._meta.fields[4]
User._meta.get_field('email')
```

### UPDATE

The Django documentation recommends you use the `clean` method for all validation that spans multiple form fields, because it's called after all the `<FIELD>.clean` and `<FIELD>_clean` methods. This means that you can (mostly) rely on the field's value being present in `cleaned_data` from within `clean`.

Since the form fields are validated in the order they're declared, I think it's okay to occasionally place multi-field validation in a `<FIELD>_clean` method, so long as the field in question appears after all other fields it depends on. I do this so any validation errors are associated with the field itself, rather than with the form.

Comment: It's more complicated. I want to setup application **django-registration** with built-in RegistrationForm. And I want to check unicity of *email* field too with *username*.

Comment: This won't work properly when you want to edit User. The validation if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count() will spoil the fun. How to check ID along with the email?

Comment: Btw, I excluded username from the ModelForm. How to do then?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the form subclass's clean method? The Django docs say at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/ that if any validation requires access to multiple fields from the form at once, it should be done in the form subclass's clean method.

Comment: @chefsmart: You're sorta right, but see my update in the answer.

Comment: So...it was a simple as he thought? User._meta.get_field('email').unique=True does what he wants.

Comment: If the user is going to register their own account, then a User ModelForm isn't so useful -- it is more work to block all the unwanted model attributes and to add in the password handling than it is just to write a "shadow" form for just username, password, email, first_name, last_name.

Comment: @IanSR: not sure I understand. How would your "shadow form" handle unique email addresses? Wouldn't you still end up with the same (or similar) code?

Comment: The method with extra database request in clean() definitely bad. What if you have several million users?

Comment: @sergzach: agreed, if you have several million users. With Django 1.5+, it's a lot easier to replace the `User` model, so you definitely want to do a custom model, and use DB constraints to handle this.

Comment: It's better to use `email__iexact` otherwise people can create two accounts with the same email address (using different capitalization).

Comment: This has a race condition - if two users are created at the same time, it may not enforce uniqueness.

Comment: @Flash: True, if you're using any isolation level other than `SERIALIZABLE`. Like I said above, my preferred solution is to create a custom User model, and use DB constraints to enforce this. Maybe I should update the answer with a warning and that recommendation?

Answer (score 41):

What about using [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in a "different" way? So far it works for me.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ('email',)
```

Comment: Clean and none intrusive.. the best. It is not easy for every one to make it easy.

Comment: @eillarra, I think this is the simplest solution. Thank you!

Comment: I also think,  this one the best solution.

Answer (score 21):

Simply use below code in models.py of any app

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution to this I've found. There may be time when one wants/needs to create a custom user model; but if the canned Django user model suffices for everything except the desire to make a standard field unique, then there's no need to complicate things. Thanks for the great answer - though you may want to add that migrations need to be performed to alter the field in that database.

Comment: Best solution! Just putted into a model.py and it works with validation and so an - THX!

Comment: You saved my day, easy and direct solution

Answer (score 17):

In settings module:

```
# Fix: username length is too small,email must be unique
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, models
User._meta.local_fields[1].__dict__['max_length'] = 75
User._meta.local_fields[4].__dict__['_unique'] = True
```

Comment: this is the only answer that **truly enforces a unique email address** at the database level, **avoids triggering premature related model resolution** (circular imports abound!), and **works correctly for the initial syncdb**. the only problem is that the field is not guaranteed to be at position X, so you must loop thru all fields and check the `name` attribute.

Comment: `User._meta.get_field('email').__dict__['_unique'] = True` or
`User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True` 
The two should work

Comment: `User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True`
This didn't work in my settings (ImportError) but perfectly worked if located in my main `__init__` module

Comment: need to use sudo when makemigrations or there would be permission denied

Comment: I needed to place this to my `models` module.

Comment: Adding this in my setting module I'm getting `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty`. on running server.

Answer (score 8):

Your form should look something like this.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    print User.objects.filter(email=email).count()
    if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'This email address is already registered.')
    return email
```

Answer (score 6):

To ensure a User, no matter where, be saved with a unique email, add this to your models:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def User_pre_save(sender, **kwargs):
    email = kwargs['instance'].email
    username = kwargs['instance'].username

    if not email: raise ValidationError("email required")
    if sender.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count(): raise ValidationError("email needs to be unique")
```

Note that this ensures non-blank email too. However, this doesn't do forms validation as would be appropriated, just raises an exception.

Comment: The fact that the ValidationError that is thrown isn't caught as part of ModelForm validation really means this isn't a usable solution, although it was interesting to learn about signals and pre_save.

Comment: Ideally the `pre_save` signalling should be used in conjunction with the form validation mentioned previously. This would help to ensure integrity across the application.

Answer (score 3):

Django has a [Full Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) on its documentation on how to substitute and use a Custom User Model, so you can add fields and use email as username.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do this is to have a pre-save hook on the User object and reject the save of the email already exists in the table.

Comment: Could you describe your suggestion in more detail, please? If I understand correctly, you are offering to use *pre-save signal* and raise *ValidationError* if email of new User exists in DB?

Comment: Where is it described what a pre-save signal should raise or return to affect the in-progress save action? I can't find it in the django docs. Am I being dumb?

Answer (score 2):

This method won't make email field unique at the database level, but it's worth trying.

Use a custom [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def validate_email_unique(value):
    exists = User.objects.filter(email=value)
    if exists:
        raise ValidationError("Email address %s already exists, must be unique" % value)
```

Then in forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from main.validators import validate_email_unique

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    #....
    email = forms.CharField(required=True, validators=[validate_email_unique])
    #....
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't protect against a race condition in which two `User` objects are trying to be created at the same time. `exists` will return false for both requests (as neither one has been saved), so both forms validate, and the result is two user objects with duplicate emails. When the constraint is at the DB level an integrity error would be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the correct answer would assure that uniqueness check was placed inside the database (and not on the django side). Because due to timing and race conditions you might end with duplicate emails in the database despite having for example `pre_save` that does proper checks.

If you really need this badly I guess you might try following approach:

1. Copy User model to your own app, and change field email to be unique.
2. Register this user model in the admin app (using admin class from `django.contrib.auth.admin`)
3. Create your own authentication backend that uses your model instead of django one.

Comment: A little of duplication but it is must safely and correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below function in any of the models.py file. Then run makemigrations and migrate. Tested on Django1.7

```
def set_email_as_unique():
    """
    Sets the email field as unique=True in auth.User Model
    """
    email_field = dict([(field.name, field) for field in MyUser._meta.fields])["email"]
    setattr(email_field, '_unique', True)

#this is called here so that attribute can be set at the application load time
set_email_as_unique()
```

Comment: There is way simplier ```User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.2 (May 11th, 2015) there has been a way to dynamically import any chosen registration form using the settings option `REGISTRATION_FORM`.

So, one could use something like this:

`REGISTRATION_FORM = 'registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail'`

This is documented [here](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default-backend.html?highlight=REGISTRATION_FORM).

And here's the link to the [changelog entry](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/f9aa6be116e4dff1a2b197ab11349cda9731d37b/CHANGELOG#L84).

Answer (score 2):

Django does not allow direct editing User object but you can add pre_save signal and achieve unique email. for create signals u can follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/. then add the following to your signals.py

```
 @receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def check_email(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    try:
        usr = User.objects.get(email=instance.email)
        if usr.username == instance.username:
            pass
        else:
            raise Exception('EmailExists')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Comment: Django does not allow direct access to User model but we can create signals on User model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/

Answer (score 1):

Add somewhere this:

```
User._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique = True
```

and then execute SQL similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer here is working for me when I'm creating new users, but it fails when I try to edit a user, since I am excluding the username from the view. Is there a simple edit for this that will make the check independent of the username field?

I also tried including the username field as a hidden field (since I don't want people to edit it), but that failed too because django was checking for duplicate usernames in the system.

(sorry this is posted as an answer, but I lack the creds to post it as a comment. Not sure I understand Stackoverflow's logic on that.)

Comment: If you don't want to show username field on form you can make it hidden and always copy value from email to username fields in clean methods or with JS on client's side. It will keep uniqueness for username.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own custom user model for this purpose. You can use email as username or phone as username , can have more than one attribute.

In your settings.py you need to specify below settings
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'.

Here is the link that can help you .
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

Answer (score -2):

from an User inherited model, redefine the attribute correctly. It should work, as is it's not usefull to have that in django core because it's simple to do.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it's not possible to redefine field, that exists in the parent model.

Answer (score -5):

I went to `\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models`
and in class `AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):`
I changed email to be:

```
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), **unique=True**, blank=True)
```

With this if you try to register with email address already present in the database you will get message: User with this Email address already exists.

Comment: this is really bad, you should never update site-packages sources like that... will you start patching the code on every server you deploy your code to?!