# Django-registration, force unique e-mail

Tags: python, django

Can I force users to make unique e-mail addresses in django-registration?

Comment: In 'POST" view             `if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():` 
                `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:unique'))` where accounts:unique in my case goes to an email not unique message to user

Answer (score 17):

For later versions of django_registration (that use class-based views), you can do this:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
        name='registration_register'),
)
```

Comment: registration.backends.default.views give you  NotImplementedError.  At run time the activate code will fail. What you need is registration.backends.hmac.views  or registration.backends.model_activation.views

Answer (score 13):

from rych's answer, I tested that the following runs ok - it only uses urls.py, you needn't write another cusotmer form.

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration.views.register',
    {'form_class': RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,
     'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},       
     name='registration_register'),
```

Comment: I have this setup. it's not working. How can I troubleshoot why? I have breakpoint just after 1st line (i.e. line 88) in site-packages/registration/forms.py `class RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(RegistrationForm):` to ensure it runs and it does, as the console returns: `RuntimeWarning)
> /Users/merty/.virtualenvs/ssc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/forms.py(92)RegistrationFormUniqueEmail()
     91 
---> 92     def clean_email(self):
     93         """

ipdb>` I then put the break at various parts of the validation conditional and it didn't pick it up as if that part's not being run?!

Answer (score 5):

[django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) has several forms included in the source – one is a [`RegistrationFormUniqueEmail`](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/registration/forms.py#cl-82), which might help you ...

---

P.S. You can adjust the form to use by changing the default backend or by implementing a custom one, where you return the appropriate form class, see: [http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/073835a4269f/registration/backends/default/**init**.py#cl-118](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/073835a4269f/registration/backends/default/__init__.py#cl-118)

Comment: Do I have to have access to django-registration files? I've changed form_class in registration definition, and nothing happened. I don't have acces to installed django-registration files. Only for django-registration files instances in my app folder.

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup, but I used to download the recent django-registration version into my projects directory, so I'm able to change files when needed (and I'm able to update the app, when needed). Also in my case, the above approach just works ...

Answer (score 4):

```
forms.py

from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class RegistroPerfilForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    first_name= forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name= forms.CharField(required=True)
    kind__of_user= forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=TIPO))
```

Comment: Doing the import in forms.py is more tidy, +1.

Answer (score 4):

As miku pointed out, you should simply use RegistrationFormUniqueEmail .

If you implement according to the documentation and bug report replies (as of mid-2011),
you'll probably end up with an exception like:

```
TypeError at /accounts/register/
register() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)
```

your urlconf should look like this to properly specify this backend:

```
(r'^accounts/register/', 'registration.views.register' {'form_class':RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, 'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

[ please excuse the additional answer, as this belongs as a comment to miku's correct answer; I don't have the privilege of commenting, but this tip may save at least a few people 15 minutes each, so is hopefully worth the forced faux-pas ]

Answer (score 2):

It should suffice to create your registration form from your user model. If the e-mail address is defined to be unique there, the form will output an error on submit for duplicate addresses.

Look [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#creating-forms-from-models) for details.

As Dominic points out, you'll not be able to do this with the built-in user profile. You'll have to extend it by creating your own user profile as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) and make it contain a unique e-mail address.

Comment: That doesn't help much when the model is one that is built-in... http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#fields

Comment: but I want cause reaction like when user try to use nick which is in use - he gets AJAX error that nick is used - I want to do the same with e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

For unique e-mail addresses in django-registration-redux 1.4.

In url.py add following

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^accounts/register/$',RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
        name='registration_register'),

 url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls'))

]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of django-registration 3.1.2, I was able to solve this in an *almost* identical way as https://stackoverflow.com/a/19383392/10987661:

```py
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/register/',
        RegistrationView.as_view(
            form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
        ),
        name='django_registration_register',
    ),
    path('accounts/', include('django_registration.backends.activation.urls')),
    ...
]
```