# Registration Form Unique Email

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using `django-inspectional-registration` which is based on the official `django-registration`.

I would like to ensure the uniqueness of the User's email field but I while I am using:

```
url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(), {'form_class' : RegistrationFormUniqueEmail},
    name='registration_register'),
```

as suggested, a new registration with the same email always pass the verification.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7377850/842935. Helps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try passing the form class as an argument to as_view

```
url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
name='registration_register')
```

Comment: I think you'll need a success_url here to redirect after registering?