# How to use registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail with django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I want to ensure I've got unique emails in my application.  Since I'm using [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/forms.html) from github I just want to use the RegistrationFormUniqueEmail instead of the standard form but I do not understand how to select the form I want to use (sorry, I know this is basic).  I've currently got it set up using the standard 2-stage registration process.

This is my current url pattern:     `url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),`

EDIT
I've added the following

```
from registration.backends.hmac.urls import RegistrationView
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
    name='registration_register'),
```

I've also changed the html link from `<a href="/accounts/register/">` to `<a href="/register/">`

The process is working as if it is using the original process still

Comment: It may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/15177001/6333890.
U should include this class form in ur URL-pattern.

Comment: Sorted, thanks - I've shown the changes I made above for anyone else