# How to use different view for django-registration?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have been trying to get django-registration to use the view RegistrationFormUniqueEmail and following the solution from this [django-registration question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131533/django-registration-force-unique-e-mail). I have set my urls.py to

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^users/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^users/register/$', 'registration.backends.default.views.RegistrationView',
        {'form_class': RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,
         'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},       
        name='registration_register'),
)
```

However, I can still create multiple accounts with the same email. What is the problem? Shouldn't django-registration be using the view that I specified? I am currently using django-registration 0.9b1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The version of Django registration you are using has been rewritten to use class based views. This means a different approach is required in your urls.py.

First, You need to subclass the RegistrationView, and set the custom form class.

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class RegistrationViewUniqueEmail(RegistrationView):
    form_class = RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
```

Then, use your custom RegistrationViewUniqueEmail subclass in your urls. As with other class based views, you must call as_view().

```
url(r'^user/register/$', RegistrationViewUniqueEmail.as_view(),
                    name='registration_register'),
```

Make sure your customised registration_register view comes before you include the default registration urls, otherwise it won't be used.

Comment: @Alasdair, Pylint for url(r'^user/register/$', RegistrationViewUniqueEmail.as_view(),
                    name='registration_register')  writes: ID:E1120  No value passed for parameter 'cls' in function call. What is that?

Comment: @Olga, Pylint sometimes brings up false positives. You can disable the error by adding `# pylint: disable=E1120` to the top of the urls.py module.

Answer (score 3):

The version *1.2* of `django-registration-redux` allows the unique email option with the following *urls.py* patterns:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail), name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

If you need to do something more, like a specific URL option, you can subclass the `RegistrationView` in your app *views.py* and `RegistrationForm` in your app *forms.py*