# How to make the email address unique in django-registration-redux?

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.7. I have installed django-registration-redux and created the templates required to render the registration form. How can I ensure that the email address is unique in the registration form. I can perhaps create custom user registration model and then give a unique constraint to the email? Are there alternatives?

I was looking at the solution earlier but this is for the "django-registration"

[Django-registration, force unique e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131533/django-registration-force-unique-e-mail)

The monkey patch in the model below seems to work but then it's just throwing a nasty error message, instead I want it throw the error message above the email field

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use this module but I have just googled and found out:

> **registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail**
>
> A subclass of RegistrationForm which enforces uniqueness of email addresses in addition to uniqueness of usernames.

[Source](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html?highlight=unique#registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail).

Update: I have read that thread carefully and even found that upvoted one of the answers there. `django-registration-redux` is just updated `django-registration` for Django 1.6/1.7. So this form `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` is exactly what you should use.

Comment: Thanks it pointed me in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379300/how-to-use-different-view-for-django-registration