# Django HMAC Registration with Unique Email

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use [RegistrationFormUniqueEmail](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/forms.html#registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail) with the [HMAC activation workflow](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/hmac.html)?

My **urls.py** looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from app.registration import RegistrationViewUniqueEmail

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationViewUniqueEmail.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]
```

I have a file **app/registration.py**

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class RegistrationViewUniqueEmail(RegistrationView):
    form_class = RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
```

I am able to complete registration i.e. the user is created in the auth_user table and I am unable to create more than one user with the same email address as expected, but I believe it is failing when the authentication email is being sent.

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/register/
(535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6')
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

(original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131533/django-registration-force-unique-e-mail) by seddonym)

The only thing to do is replace

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
```

with

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView
```