# Django-registration unique email with hmac backend

Tags: django, django-registration

I use django-registration package in my app. Is it possible to use unique email while using the (proposed by the documentation) hmac backend?

I have found many posts that answer for the model backend, not the hmac.

Edit: Notice that I am not talking about default or model backend, but HMAC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-registration, force unique e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131533/django-registration-force-unique-e-mail)

Comment: All these are about default backend.. In hmac you can't have registration in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://djangohmac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Please be as specific as possible when asking questions. [Ask] has some great tips for asking effective questions.

Comment: @kopsti I don't see anything in that answer that depends on having anything in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @MichaelMior If i don't have 'registration' included in INSTALLED_APPS, how will I use tthis import ?
'from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail' I will get an error. Am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need to have the app in your INSTALLED_APPS to be able to import something.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

It was a duplicate as mentioned (original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131533/django-registration-force-unique-e-mail) by seddonym), sorry for my misunderstanding.

The only thing to do is replace

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
```

with

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView
```