# Making email field unique with Django User admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

There was a nearly similar question: [How to make email field unique in model User from contrib.auth in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160030/how-to-make-email-field-unique-in-model-user-from-contrib-auth-in-django)

The solution was not perfect: Validating email for uniqueness. The solution provided is rather funny. It disallows modifications to User that leave email intact. How to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: which of the proposed solutions are you talking about? the accepted solution?

Comment: I answered in the other question. I think this one should be closed as it is a complete duplicate.

Comment: Which one? Are you sure that question and your answer meet my requirements? Thanks.

Comment: I edited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160030/how-to-make-email-field-unique-in-model-user-from-contrib-auth-in-django/1164583#1164583 and i think it now meets your requirements.

Comment: +1 thanks! U earned my vote twice =) Maybe I need a book on Django. There are little details that I miss.

Comment: Btw, I excluded username from the ModelForm. How to do then?

Comment: Who down-voted this without an explanation???? The question has been 1 year and 8 months with no issues!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Ofri Raviv but what I've seen is not what I needed. So I resolved my own issue and now I'd like to share the tips:

1. Use username instead of email, exclude email from the form. Mask its label as email.
2. Subclass User and create a UNIQUE field which receives email addresses, mask it as email, exclude original email field from the form.

It's that simple but took me some time. Hope it help others with the same need.

Answer (score 17):

in your `__init__.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique = True
```

Comment: monkey-pathcing is bad, but contib.auth is so badly designed, that using monkey-patching here should be no shame at all.

Comment: I ask clarification about init.py, please. There are tens of __init__.py in my project. Which one is the one you mean? Hmm.. stackoverflow does not show underlines, this confuses...

Comment: Actually every __init__.py will do. But i would recommend the one located in the root dir.

Comment: +1 Thanks, but in  __init__.py i had this error:  `AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")` ... i tried to add this code in wsgi.py and now it works. Django==1.7.1 :)

Comment: Thanks, but i had this error: `AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_field_by_name'` ... i change the second line to `User._meta.get_field("email")._unique = True` and now it works. Django==1.10.4

Answer (score 0):

This method won't make email field unique at the database level, but it's worth trying.

Use a custom [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def validate_email_unique(value):
    exists = User.objects.filter(username=value)
    if exists:
        raise ValidationError("Email address %s already exits, must be unique" % value)
```

Then in forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from main.validators import validate_email_unique


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    #....
    email = forms.CharField(required=True, validators=[validate_email_unique])
    #....
```

Comment: This solution is a little flawed in that UserForm could only be used to create users. If you used it to edit a User, "exists" would be true even though that is an expected result.