# Making EMail address unique in DJango authentication system

Tags: django, email, authorization

I need to make the EMail field of the DJango authentication system unique.

I am using Python 3.6.3 and DJango 1.11.7

In order to do so, I found this:
[Making email field unique with Django User admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278855/making-email-field-unique-with-django-user-admin)

When following it, I add the code below to `__init__.py` under the application folder that represents the authentication. I have also tried adding it to the `__init_-.py` file for the project.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field("email")._unique = True
```

Either way, I still get the same error (which is listed below). How do I solve it?

TIA

```
C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\python.exe manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001F9D03BCEA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\WORK\AppPython\ContractorsClubBackofficeCode\authorization\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

## Update

Hi @solarissmoke and thanks for the input!

I am new to DJango - and - am still learning :-)  I have the following defined in. Looking for checks to be done at the DB level.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from authorization.models import UserProfileInfo, Mstrgenstate, Mstrgencountry, Mstrgenstoretype, Mstrgensalutationtype, Mstrgenbusinesstype

class UserForm (forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

    def clean_email(self):
        # Get the email
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email as a username.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email

        # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
        raise forms.ValidationError( "This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.")


    def clean_username(self):
        # Get the username
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email as a username.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return username

        # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
        raise forms.ValidationError("This userid is already in use. Please supply a different userid.")

class UserProfileInfoForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('approle', 'profilepic')
```

Here, the model I am using is called `User`. In the sample you mantioned, you named it `MyUser`. I am to make the changes below as well:

FROM:

```
class Meta():
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

TO:

```
class Meta():
    model = MyUser
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

Right?

TIA

Answer (score 4):

The solution you linked to is 7 years old, and definitely not the way to do it any more.

The better way to do this sort of thing is to use a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). In your case you would override the `email` field to make it unique:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

If the email is going to be the unique identifier for users (i.e., that is what they use to log in), then you will also want to set:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

on your user class.

Finally tell Django to use this new user model in your settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Pls see the Update portion. I just need to make sure the email acts as though it is unique. It will not replace the login-name as the ID for the table overall.

Comment: In that case don't change `USERNAME_FIELD`. You still need to set the `email` field in the model as unique. Trying to check for an existing user with that email in the `clean` method is not safe from race conditions (e.g., if two users try to register at the same time).

Comment: Thanks again for the response. That is good to know :) I was looking for a solution at the Model level. The database I am using is Oracle. I have already added a unique constraint on the EMAIL field there. But, for me - this is the "last resort". I am using the DJango "User" model in this case [ see updates in the message above] - so - I don't really have an actual model (per se) to set the email to work with. What can I do in this situation?