# Django Email As User Name

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there any way I can use email as user name with out specifying custom user model. I am new to django, From past few hour I am searching and trying to find a way. I try creating custom modal but then everything get changed like admin login.

Secondly is there any way to define a  custom model for specific app. eg. fronted only. So that back-end stay as is.

I just need to use email as username for users login.

Is it possible to use

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773970/django-auth-user-with-unique-email

Comment: This is a hack. I am wondering if there is proper solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668124/can-i-change-the-username-field-in-django-1-5-without-creating-a-custom-user#15681648

Comment: @Waqas If you want i can provide the details for how to login using email and without username...

Comment: Why doesn't USERNAME_FIELD work for you? Is it because your email field is not unique? Or because you want to be able to login by username too?

Comment: For user name field don't I have to define custom model? Which will again change everything.

Answer (score 1):

I actually end up using django-authtools

Answer (score 0):

Get the email and password using form

```
email = form.cleaned_data['email']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
```

If the given email matches with exiting record.

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    if user.check_password(password):
        username = user.username
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Welcome {}".format(email))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Password not match for  {}".format(email))
except User.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```