# Make User email unique django

Tags: python, django

How can I make a Django User email unique when a user is signing up?

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I'm using the from django.contrib.auth.models User.
Do I need to override the User in the model. Currently the model doesn't make a reference to User.

**views.py**

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Comment: For all coming here, @Mohamed Emad answer is the most djangoish way if you do not want to implement a CustomUser

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The best answer is to use `CustomUser` by subclassing the `AbstractUser` and put the unique email address there. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

and update the settings with `AUTH_USER_MODEL="app.CustomUser"`.

But if its not necessary for you to store the unique email in Database or maybe not use it as username field, then you can update the form's `clean` method to put a validation. For example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class YourForm(UserCreationForm):

    def clean(self):
       email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
       if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email exists")
       return self.cleaned_data
```

#### Update

If you are in mid project, then you can follow the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) on how to change migration, in short which is to:

1. Backup you DB
2. Create a custom user model identical to auth.User, call it User (so many-to-many tables keep the same name) and set db_table='auth_user' (so it uses the same table)
3. Delete all Migrations File(except for `__init__.py`)
4. Delete all entry from table `django_migrations`
5. Create all migrations file using `python manage.py makemigrations`
6. Run fake migrations by `python manage.py migrate --fake`
7. Unset `db_table`, make other changes to the custom model, generate migrations, apply them

But if you are just starting, then delete the DB and migrations files in migration directory except for `__init__.py`. Then create a new DB, create new set of migrations by `python manage.py makemigrations` and apply migrations by `python manage.py migrate`.

And for references in other models, you can reference them to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to avoid any future problems. For example:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

It will automatically reference to the current User Model.

Comment: So when I try to add the CustomUser I get an error as there are other models that use the django.contrib.auth.User. Trying to figure out what i need to do to extend the User model. Do I need to change all references from User to CustomUser?

Comment: @mogoli See my comment above. You need to remove db, migrations, etc. and then start the project over.

Comment: I know this was posted long time ago, but I have a problem with a CustomUser as in the solution in post above.I have a CustomUser with an email field and I discovered I'm getting an integrity error when I want to create a new user in admin panel. The error message is: "IntegrityError at /admin/users/customuser/add/. I created the CustomUser when starting a project, but email field was added later.. I wonder if this may be the issue..
duplicate key value violates unique constraint  users_customuser_email_6445acef_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
".

Comment: @ruddra what do you mean by "But if it's not necessary for you to store the unique email in Database...", isn't checking if the email is unique in the `UserForm` same as storing unique email in the `User model`? e.g. if I want to use email and password as my primary fields for login, then will checking if the email is unique in the `UserForm` do my job, or should I create `CustomUser` model by inheriting from `AbstractUser`?

Answer (score 32):

Here is a working code

Use the below code snippets in any of your models.py

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

django version : 3.0.2

Reference : [Django auth.user with unique email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773970/django-auth-user-with-unique-email)

Comment: By far the easiest method to constrain the User model email address to unique - you can even incorporate it into existing projects if there are not already non-unique values in the table.

Comment: this sounds more like a hack than a djangoish method

Answer (score 5):

Working Code for Django 3.1

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
SETTINGS.PY
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Just need to do `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` just after editing model.py

Answer (score 3):

There is a great example of this in Django's docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example.

You have to declare the email field in your `AbstractBaseUser` model as `unique=True`.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: When I try this, nothing happens, my signup for still can accept duplicate emails

Comment: @mogoli Remove your db and migrations. In settings.py, add `AUTH_USER_MODEL='new_user_model.MyUser'. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations new_user`. Lastly, run `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way:
you can user signal
Example

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import  receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ValidationError

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def check_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    email = instance.email
    if sender.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=instance.username).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Email Already Exists')
```

Comment: The problem with this is when you want to change your stack but keep the db, anyways, am rolling with this!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in:

> [django-user-unique-email](https://pypi.org/project/django-user-unique-email/)
>
> Reusable User model with required unique email field and mid-project support.

It defines custom User model reusing of the original table (auth_user) if exists. If needed (when added to existing project), it recreates history of applied migrations in the correct order.

I'll appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing then using `AbstractBaseUser`

```
#forms.py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.form import UserCreationForm
from some_app.validators import validate_email

def validate_email(value):
    if User.objects.filter(email = value).exists():
        raise ValidationError((f"{value} is taken."),params = {'value':value})

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(validators = [validate_email])
        
        class Meta:
            model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way. And it shows the error at form's error codes.

Answer (score 1):

In case of use **CustomUser** model inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` you can override the `full_clean()` method to validate unique constraints on the model fields you specified `unique=True`. This is safer than form (i.e. `FormClass`) validation.

**Example**:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    # ...


    def full_clean(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Call clean_fields(), clean(), and validate_unique() on the model.
        Raise a ValidationError for any errors that occur.
        """
        super().full_clean()
```

**Note**: Tested on [Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)

Answer (score 0):

## Improvement for solution with form validation

Instead of raising a `ValidationError`, it would be better to use the [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method so that all errors of the forms are sent, and not only the one raised by `ValidationError`.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            msg = 'A user with that email already exists.'
            self.add_error('email', msg)           
    
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit model in meta as follow

- Note: This will not update the original model

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        model._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
```