# Django 3: Setting user email to be unique, minimal viable solution

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I'm writing a simple app, and I'm totally happy with Django User model, except that I want a user email to be unique and obligatory field.
I have developed a solution, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

a) If you think that something is missing in the solution below please let me know

b) If you think that you have a better solution please share

This is what I did

1. Created a custom user model

```py
# customers/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email', unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

2. Added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customers.User' to settings.py
3. Changed a reference to User model:

```py
   User = get_user_model()
```

4. Modified admin.py in order to be able to add users using Django admin.

```py
# customers/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff')

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make User email unique django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461410/make-user-email-unique-django)

Comment: Not exactly, I want a bare minimum solution which ensures a unique email and non-broken django authentication system.

Comment: Minimum would be to ensure all user creation happens using the same form and that form does a query on the `User` table to ensure that the value of the `email` field in the form is unique against the database.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one you are looking for

Use the below code snippets in any of your models.py

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

django version : 3.0.2

Reference : [Django auth.user with unique email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773970/django-auth-user-with-unique-email)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075027/6651010