# In Django correct way of extending a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the best way to extend third party model in django 1.5?
Suppose I have 3rd party model called Feedback:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        related_name='feedback_form_submissions',
        blank=True, null=True,
    )

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('Email'),
        blank=True,
    )
    ...
```

I have my own user class. I need to override the user field. email I need to make blank=False and presumably want to add another Field to the model. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: unfortunately they should have used the correct conventions in creating an app that supports custom user model (using AUTH_USER_MODEL) it might be easiest and cleanest to fork their project and make the correct updates

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the circumstance, that is, which 3rd party app you are using, you can approach this in a variety of ways:

1. Explicity inheriting from a model:

   class CustomFeedback(Feedback):
       #etc
2. Create a custom app:
   Extend the app by doing a `django-admin.py startapp AppName_custom` which is a technique I have used with some apps. In that case you will want to inheret from a class like above but intercept DB methods like `save` or `clean`.
3. Fork the app. This is easily the most difficult way of doing this if you are inexperienced with Django. Just clone or fork via `git` or `mercurial` then add whatever code you need to modify the behavior of the app.

As a rule of thumb (pardon the expression) you shoudln't modify the `User` model since the `Auth` module is nicely comparmentalized. Instead you should use an app like [`django-profiles`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home) to add data to models or extend Forms.

Comment: I beg you pardon, but if I extend the the app by inheriting from the class how can I change the user field? Django explicitly forbids the field hiding and overriding https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. If you are customizing a form you can just leave it out of the ```fields``` attribute. If you are trying to modify the model fields themselves I would think about how that impacts the principle "Don't Repeat Yourself." Again, I'm not sure I understand your follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this post? [How to make email field unique in model User from contrib.auth in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160030/how-to-make-email-field-unique-in-model-user-from-contrib-auth-in-django)

I think it answers everything you want.

Django also includes documentation on how to do this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

You can also designate a custom User model for Django to use with AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'. From there you can set your custom fields.