# Django rest auth email instead of username

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have a django project in which I am using Django-rest-auth to do authentication. I want to use ***email with password*** to authenticate the user and not the username+password.

I have following settings in my settings.py but it didn't do anything for me:

```
REST_SESSION_LOGIN = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'EMAIL'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: 1. Do you get any errors? 2. Do you have a custom user model? 3. Did you try the following settings? http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models

Answer (score 36):

Following setting worked:

```
#This is required otherwise it asks for email server
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'EMAIL'
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True   
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

#Following is added to enable registration with email instead of username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
 "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

 # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
 "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this package too, and by call this config it worked for me:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

Be careful about this config, this config belongs to `django-allauth`, see this:

```
class AuthenticationMethod:
    USERNAME = 'username'
    EMAIL = 'email'
    USERNAME_EMAIL = 'username_email'
```

The above class is the settings which is in `allauth`, so you should write 'EMAIL' in lower case.