# Registration with django-rest-auth: where to set allauth settings (email verification/required username)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm using `django-rest-auth` with the registration add-on, which uses `django-allauth` to implement signup, confirmation, social sign-in, etc endpoints. It's largely working, however I can't figure out where to put certain settings such that the registration and other auth endpoints will respect various `allauth` settings. My current issues are:

1. Users can login without verifying their email- the `allauth` setting ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION (default='optional') controls whether this is mandatory
2. Users must provide a username at signup, despite one not being required by my user model (email address is my username field)- the `allauth` setting ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED (default=True) controls this

I've attempted to add the above settings to resolve these issues, but the registration and login endpoints don't seem to respect them. For example, from my `settings.py`:

```
....
ALLAUTH = {
    'ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION': 'mandatory',
    'ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED': False,
}
....
```

However, in looking at both the `allauth` and `django-rest-auth` serializers, the `allauth` settings are checked in the following manner (from the `django-rest-auth` `LoginSerializer`):

```
# If required, is the email verified?
    if 'rest_auth.registration' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        from allauth.account import app_settings
        if app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION == app_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY:
            email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
            if not email_address.verified:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_('E-mail is not verified.'))
```

Looking at the `django-rest-auth/registration` `RegisterSerializer` is similar:

```
try:
  from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
  from allauth.utils import (email_address_exists,
                           get_username_max_length)
  from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
  from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email
except ImportError:
  raise ImportError('allauth needs to be added to INSTALLED_APPS.')
....
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  username = serializers.CharField(
    max_length=get_username_max_length(),
    min_length=allauth_settings.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
    required=allauth_settings.USERNAME_REQUIRED
  )
  email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
  password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
  password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
```

In both places, the `allauth` settings are imported directly from `allautha.account.app_settings` instead of `settings.py`, as I'd expect. In the `allauth` source on github, I can see the `app_settings` file, however does that mean I need to place my desired settings there? Isn't the point of `settings.py` to be a single spot to collate settings for installed apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out- this turned out to be pretty easy, and I guess something I *could* have gathered from the docs, though its far from clear.

Rather than defining `allauth` settings in `settings.py` like this:

```
....
ALLAUTH = {
'ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION': 'mandatory',
'ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED': False,
}
....
```

It needs to be done like this:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

Just directly in `settings.py`, no identifier needed. I'm not sure why they aren't in their own section, but this definitely works. Hopefully you don't have another app with identically named settings- though I'm sure there's a way around that.

I found [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698456/django-rest-auth-email-instead-of-username) that clued me in.