# How to login with username or email in Django | rest_framework_jwt?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, customization

I would like to log in pages with both `username` and `email`, I wrote a `CustomBackend` view to auth no matter how I changed, only `username` works, I use "email" to log in pages, always got error of`Unable to log in with provided credentials`, partial code of views.py as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

MyUser = get_user_model()

class CustomBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(Q(username=username)|Q(email=username))
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            MyUser().set_password(password)
```

partial code of settings.py as below:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'general.views.CustomBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you need to add custom model for `user` and specify `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, as far as know, `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` can't log in with both 'username' and 'email', only `email`, I wanna two fields

Comment: Your code looks good so you’ll need to debug more in detail. Set a breakpoint in your authenticate method and check where it’s failing. Or add print statements to know which path is being followed.

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316765/log-in-user-using-either-email-address-or-username-in-django