# I'm trying to create a login form in django with both username and password to be my phone number provided while registration

Tags: django, authentication

Here is my models.py, im using these details for registration after registration i want the user to login with phone_number as his username and password. I tried custom ModelBackend but couldn't come with up solution

**models.py**

```
class userModel(models.Model):

Full_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
Date_of_Birth = models.DateField()
Phone_Number = models.CharField(max_length = 10,unique=True,null=False,blank=False)
Email_ID = models.EmailField()
Passport_Number = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Full_Name
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
   registered = False

   if request.method == 'POST':
       user_form = userForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if user_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.save()
         registered = True
    else:
        print(user_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = userForm()

return render(request,'dezzexapp/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered})
```

Answer (score 0):

About the part with using your phone number as login, you can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25437110) on logging in with another method (if you want both methods to stay, keep the old Django middleware; if you want to replace it, remove the existing auth middleware).

About the password part, I don't think that's necessary. **As long as your phone numbers are unique**, I believe that you can directly check whether the phone number matches a user in the database. However, if you insist on two passwords, here's how you should do it.

For the example that I provided you with, you might need two password fields for a user, one for the regular one and another for the phone. But modify like this:

```py
if user.check_password(password1) or user.check_password(password2):
```

and then that should make both passwords valid for the user.

Comment: i want the username as well password to be my phone number which i provide during registration